# Nativescript + Angular, is there a plugin available for a math oriented keyboard or how to create a keyboard with most math symbols

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I've been trying to find ways to implement a keyboard with the full or almost full inclusion of all the symbols. For example like mathway. If there isn't one i would love to know.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af08k.png

Comment: Unfortunately, no there isn't a ready made plugin. You will have to build your own keyboard layout.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MathKeyboardEngine](https://github.com/MathKeyboardEngine/MathKeyboardEngine#readme). It provides the logic for a highly customizable virtual math keyboard.

When using MathKeyboardEngine, you also need to choose typesetting library, for example [ng-katex](https://github.com/garciparedes/ng-katex).

With the combination of those two libraries, you can create math keyboards with a huge amount of symbols. Test the [live examples](https://mathkeyboardengine.github.io/) to get an idea of what is possible.